# Can a linked list be sorted by changing the references?

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort

I'm trying to sort a linked list using bubble sort algorithm, by changing the references of nodes. I have searched through a lot of books and on the internet, but I have only found sort methods that changes the values from the information part between nodes.
What I want to do is sorting by changing the order of traveling the list, not the values between them.
Here's my code.
PS: The sort algorithm does not work.
It's not duplicate of merge sort list, because it's entirely another algorithm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LINESIZE 128
struct Student {
    float medie;
    char nrMatricol[10];
    char *nume;
    char facltate[6];
};
struct Nod{
    Student stud;
    Nod* next;
};
Nod* inserareNodEnd(Nod *l,Student st)
{
    Nod *nou = (Nod*)malloc(sizeof(Nod));
    nou->next = NULL;//NOU->NEXT=0
    nou->stud = st;
    if (!l) {
        //lista este goala
        return nou;
    }
    else
    {
     //lista contine un nod
        Nod *t = l;
        while (t->next) {
            t = t->next;
        }
        t->next = nou;
        return l;
    }

}
float medieStudenti(Nod *lista) {
    float suma=0;
    int i=0;
    Nod *aux=lista;
    while (aux->next) {
        aux = aux->next;
        suma += aux->stud.medie;
        i++;
    }
    return suma/i;
}
Nod *stergerePrimulNodLista(Nod *l,Student *st) {
    if (l) {
        Nod *aux = l;
        l = l->next;
        aux->next = NULL;
        *st = aux->stud;
        //aux->next = NULL;
        free(aux);

    }
        return l;
}
Nod* sortareLista(Nod *l) {
    Nod *i=l;
    Nod *j=l;
    Nod *aux=l;
    Nod *min=l;
    min = i;
    while (i->next) {

        if (i->stud.medie < min->stud.medie) {
            min = i;
        }
        i = i->next;

    }
    i = l;
    int n = 0;
    while (i->next) {
        j = i->next;
        while (j->next) {
            if (i->stud.medie > j->stud.medie) {
                aux = i->next;
                i->next = j->next;
                j->next = aux;
            }
            j = j->next;
        }
        i = i->next;
    }

    return min;
    //return l;
}
void dezalocare(Nod *lista) {
    Nod *aux;
    aux = lista;
    while (aux->next) {
        lista = aux->next;
        free(aux->stud.nume);
        free(aux);
        aux = lista;
    }
}
void main()
{
    FILE *f;
    Student s;
    Nod *list=NULL;
    f = fopen("fisier.txt", "r");
    char fileBuff[LINESIZE], SEPARATORI[] = { "," };
    char *token;
    while (fgets(fileBuff, LINESIZE, f)) {
        token = strtok(fileBuff, SEPARATORI);
        strcpy(s.nrMatricol, token);
        //extragere token nume student din aceeasi linie
        //salvata in file Buff
        token = strtok(NULL, SEPARATORI);
        s.nume = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(token) + 1);
        strcpy(s.nume, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, SEPARATORI);
        strcpy(s.facltate, token);
        //extragere tokeni medie si conversia tokenului la float
        token = strtok(NULL, SEPARATORI);
        s.medie = atof(token);
        list = inserareNodEnd(list, s);
        printf("%s %s \n", s.nrMatricol, s.nume);
    }
    Nod *tmp = list;
    while (tmp) {
        printf("\nSe afiseaza din lista");
        printf("%s %s \n", tmp->stud.nrMatricol, tmp->stud.nume);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    fclose(f);
    //determinarea mediei pentru studentii din lista
    float media = medieStudenti(list);
    printf("\nMedia este %.2f", media);
    //sortare lista dupa medie(cu modificarea adreselor de legatura)

    //tema dezalocare lista
    //tema dezalocari la nivel de aplicatie
    printf("\nAcesta este Ionel %s %s \n", s.nrMatricol, s.nume);
//  list = stergerePrimulNodLista(list, &s);
    tmp = list;
    while (tmp) {
        printf("\nSe afiseaza din lista");
        printf("%s %s \n", tmp->stud.nrMatricol, tmp->stud.nume);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

     tmp = list;
    while (tmp) {
        printf("\nSe afiseaza  lista sortata");
        printf("%s %s \n", tmp->stud.nrMatricol, tmp->stud.nume);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    dezalocare(list);
  }
```

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate of the question about merge sort because the concensus seems to be that it's the best algorithm for sorting a linked list by rearranging the links.

Comment: it's not duplicate .This question ask how to merge 2 lists.Please ,read it again  //Merge subroutine to merge two sorted lists .You get it now?

Comment: NOTE: `struct Nod{
    Student stud;
    Nod* next;
};` is a syntax error in C.Are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: Visual Studio.It's working fine

Comment: @CovrigGeorge-Manuel That's just a subroutine within the sorting algorithm. The main algorithm is sorting one linked list.

Comment: I was particulary interested in how to implement buble sort on a linked list.It odes not help me

Comment: Link to [example of bubble sort for linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033800/bubble-sort-implementation-on-linked-lists/42356819#42356819) . It's a Java example. In the case of C or C++, a pointer to pointer to node could be used instead of a dummy node.

Comment: it does not work .It remains in aninfinite loop

Comment: First: bubblesort is terrible. For linked lists, it is even more terrible...
[the "natural" way to sort a linked list is merge-sort, because zip-merging two sorted linked lists is easy]

Comment: @Barmar - It appears that the OP specifically wants to implement bubble sort. As far as the "best" algorithm for sorting a linked list, although the bottom up merge sort I show in my answer in the "duplicate" thread as fastest for a linked list sort, it's faster to move the list to an array, sort the array, and create a new list from the sorted array. If the nodes are large enough, it would be fastest to create an array of pointers to the nodes and sort the array of pointers, then create a new list.

Comment: OK, I've reopened the question. Good luck with your silly goal.

Comment: @Barmar - thanks. It's the OP's goal, not mine.

Comment: @rcgldr That's who I was referring to.

Comment: I had my silly answer ready, too ;-)

Comment: Now that the `duplicate` link has been removed, the link to merge sort was also lost. Here's a link to [bottom up merge sort for linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685/merge-sort-a-linked-list/33987943#33987943) , which is much more efficient, but it's faster still to move a list to an array, sort the array, then create a new list from the sorted array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested by original poster, example of a bubble sort for linked list.

*Update* - removed `swap`, using pnEnd (ptr to end of unsorted list) instead.

```
/* bubble sort linked list */

NODE * SortList(NODE *pHead)    /* pHead used as local ptr to start of list */
{
NODE *pEnd = NULL;              /* ptr to end of unsorted part of list */
NODE *pnEnd;                    /* pEnd for next pass */
NODE *pNext;                    /* ptr to next node */
NODE **ppCurr;                  /* ptr to ptr to curr node */
    if(pHead == NULL)           /* return if empty list */
        return pHead;
    do{
        ppCurr = &pHead;        /* set ppCurr to start of list */
        pnEnd = pHead->next;    /* set pnEnd to 2nd node */
        while((pNext = (*ppCurr)->next) != pEnd){
            if((*ppCurr)->data > pNext->data){ /* if out of order swap */
                (*ppCurr)->next = pNext->next;
                pnEnd = pNext->next = *ppCurr;
                *ppCurr = pNext;
            }
            ppCurr = &(*ppCurr)->next;
        }
        pEnd = pnEnd;           /* update pEnd since rest of list is sorted */
    }while(pEnd != pHead->next);
    return pHead;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!I'll mark this as the correct answer as soon as I verify it

Comment: @CovrigGeorge-Manuel - I updated my answer, removed `swap`, added `pnEnd`.

Answer (score 0):

First: bubblesort is terrible.
For linked lists, it is even more terrible...
[the "natural" way to sort a linked list is merge-sort, because zip-merging two sorted linked lists is easy]

For bubble sort,the elementary operation is:

- { compare two adjacent nodes, and MAYBE swap them }
- and repeat this until nothing changes.
- which implies that the final pass always does nothing.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node{
        struct node *next;
        int value;
        };

struct node nodes[] =
{{ nodes+1, 9}
,{ nodes+2, 5}
,{ nodes+3, 0}
,{ nodes+4, 1}
,{ nodes+5, 4}
,{ nodes+6, 7}
,{ nodes+7, 2}
,{ nodes+8, 3}
,{ nodes+9, 8}
,{ NULL   , 6}
        };

void node_printlist(struct node *p) {
for (   ;p; p=p->next) {
        printf("%d\n", p->value);
        }
}

unsigned node_bubblepass(struct node **pp)
{
struct node *one, *two;
unsigned swaps;

for (swaps=0 ; one = *pp; pp=&(*pp)->next) {
        two = one->next;
        if(!two) break;
        if(two->value >= one->value) continue;
                /* wrong order: swap them*/
        one->next = two->next;
        two->next = one;
        *pp = two;
        swaps++;
        }
return swaps;
}

void node_bubblesort(struct node **pp)
{
unsigned swaps;
do      {
        swaps = node_bubblepass(pp);
        } while (swaps);
}

int main(void){
struct node *root =nodes;

printf("Original:\n");
node_printlist(root);

node_bubblesort(&root);

printf("Result:\n");
node_printlist(root);

return 0;
}
```

---

UPDATE (thanks to @rcgldr) in the innerloop we can stop to bubble down when we hit an item that has been bubbled down before.

```
struct node * node_bubblepass_2(struct node **pp, struct node *end)
{
struct node *one, *two;

for ( ; one = *pp; pp=&(*pp)->next) {
        two = one->next;
        if(two == end) break;
        if(two->value >= one->value) continue;
                /* wrong order: swap them*/
        one->next = two->next;
        two->next = one;
        *pp = two;
        }
return one;
}

void node_bubblesort_2(struct node **pp)
{
 struct node *end = NULL;
do      {
        end = node_bubblepass_2(pp, end);
        } while (*pp != end);
}
```

Comment: Since your answer has been updated, I deleted my prior comments. I'll delete this comment later.